# android app not displaying as expected

Tags: android, xml, display, android-gridlayout

I'm using android studio to create a simple calculator app using the GridLayout. However, it's not displaying on my device (yes, running it on my old note5 rather than emulator because it's goes a lot faster).  In android studio in the design tab of the xml file it shows how I'd expect it to be, however when I run the app on my phone, thing's are a little weird. I'll post the screenshot of the app running on my phone as well as a screenshot of android studio design tab. I'll also post my full xml code in my activity_main.xml.

My Phone: 
[image]

Android Studio:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.pvtboromeo.test.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="4"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:gravity="bottom|right"
        android:paddingRight="15sp"
        android:paddingBottom="15sp"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:text="TEST" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonC"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="C"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonNegative"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="+/-"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPercent"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="%" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonDivide"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button2"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="/" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSeven"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="7"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonEight"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="8"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonNine"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonMultiply"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button2"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="X" />

</GridLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
android:layout_rowWeight="1"
android:layout_columnWeight="1"
```

this attribute is only used in API21 and higher. you should use supportv7 
 GridLayout instead.
add this

```
 compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
```

in your module's `build.gradle`. 
then change you xml like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.pvtboromeo.test.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_row="0"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_columnSpan="4"
        app:layout_rowSpan="2"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:gravity="bottom|right"
        android:paddingRight="15sp"
        android:paddingBottom="15sp"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:text="TEST" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonC"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_row="2"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="C"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonNegative"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_row="2"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="+/-"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPercent"
        app:layout_row="2"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="%" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonDivide"
        app:layout_row="2"
        app:layout_column="3"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="/" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSeven"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_row="3"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="7"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonEight"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_row="3"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="8"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonNine"
        app:layout_row="3"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonMultiply"
        app:layout_row="3"
        app:layout_column="3"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="X" />

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

notice, this is `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout` not `android.widget.GridLayout`, and the attribute is
`app:layout_rowWeight="1"` not `android:layout_rowWeight="1"`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a ConstraintLayout. Is the better way to do layouts with a lot of view.

It's the best way to have good performance too (and you need less time to program it).

More neasted view you have, more slowly works your activity.

For a simple layout of a calculator you can try to see my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.moris.calcolatricelayoutconstraint.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView24"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="/"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textView6"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView21" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView25"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="x"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView22" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView26"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="="
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView23" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView21"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="-"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView24"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textView6"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView18" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView22"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="+"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView25"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView19" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView23"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="%"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView26"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView20" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView18"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="8"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView21"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textView6"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView15" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView19"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="7"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView22"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView16" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView20"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="9"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView23"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView17" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="5"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView18"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textView6"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView16"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="4"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView19"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView17"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="6"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView20"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Insert numbers"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView15"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textView6"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView16"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView17"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
```

To do the border, I've created this xml file call "border", in drawable resource, and use that in the TextView's background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<stroke
    android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:width="2dp"/>

<corners
    android:radius="5dp"/>
```

If you want learn more about ConstraintLayout: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

In particulary, watch the video 4.